# Regex to match text between two strings, including the strings

Tags: regex

I'm trying to fix some conflicts in a merge by git, there are a lot of <<<<<< HEAD and ====== blocks I want to be able to just find and replace with an empty string in a lot of files.

I found this regex pattern that correctly matches everything between the two strings, but it leaves out the beginning and ending strings, and I want to be able to match them also.

```
(?s)(?<=<<<<<<< HEAD).*?(?=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=)
```

So, match <<<<<<< HEAD, ======= and everything between them to do a search/replace.

Can anyone help me out? I would be running this on files I'm certain I don't want anything between those strings, I guess that's also why I didn't try a "use theirs" flag when doing the merge, because I need to see the files first.

Comment: Hint: `(?<=`…`)` and `(?=`…`)` are called look-arounds. They just look, whether a substring is there but don’t match it.

Comment: What editor/tool are you using?  How many files do you have?  For just a handful of files I would personally prefer to do it by hand.

Comment: they're over 100 files

Comment: and I'm using Phpstorm

Comment: so, @Xufox, what I need is to find the equivalent of those look arounds then? could you tell me what should I be looking for for a substitution of the look arounds?

Comment: Just remove them. You don’t need to look around and you don’t need to find any equivalent.

Comment: I tried with this: (?s)(?<<<<<<< HEAD).*?(?=\=\=\=\=\=\=\=) can can match also the first string, but can't figure out how to match also the ending ==== part

Comment: `<<<<<<< HEAD\n.*\n=======` ... this will match what you want, but the suggestion to use a merge tool is a good one.

Comment: ah I was missing the second \n there.... this should work, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just leave out the look-arounds mentioned by Xufox

```
(?s)(<<<<<<< HEAD)(.*?)(\=\=\=\=\=\=\=)
```

The `.*?` is wrapped with parentheses so you can reference it in the replacement. `\1` for the first group, `\2` for the second, and `\3` for everything in between (but the syntax can vary.)

Comment: In the spirit of regex you should have probably have used <{7} and \={7}

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be asking the wrong question here. The best way to actually handle merge conflicts is with a merge tool. You should look into something like meld. And specifically setting git merge tool to use that. Manual merges are not fun...

Use a pretty ui to analyze the merge instead

Comment: thanks, I didn't know that tool, but it would still be overkill since most of the files have at least a couple dozen of those conflicts, that's why I thought a regex solution might be faster

Comment: @andrux You would be surprised. It is very pretty and there were conflicts for a reason. Are you absolutely sure you always want to take the new code and not the code you are conflicting with?  In which case your original question doesn't even handle the close >>>>>>>>> commit message

Comment: well, the closing commit message I can just search and replace with an empty string, it's the same string anyway... and yes, I'm sure about taking always new code, I'm updating a php web app with the latest version from the author, and I only did some changes to some files, so the files I modified I want to manually review them, the rest I want to take whatever the author changed

Answer (score 0):

You want to match on the opening and closing tags of the conflict sections?

Parentheses are primarily used for group capturing, if you do like so:

```
(<<<<<<< HEAD)(.*\s)+(\s*=======)
```

It will create 4 groups which you can access the members.

Tested: http://regexr.com/